# Adding new classes when user changes type

Tags: javascript, html, css

I posted a similar question yesterday and got some helpful responses but the problem I am having now is slightly different. When the user changes the `type` on the UI, classes are added to the html elements (this simply adds a blue border around the element). I'm not receiving any error messages but it's just not doing anything.

```js
document.querySelector(DOM.inputType).addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (usersInput.type === "Health") {
    document.querySelector('.input_type').className += " blue";
    document.querySelector('.input_activity').className += " blue";
    document.querySelector('.input_time').className += " blue";
    document.querySelector('.input_end').className += " blue";
    document.querySelector('.input_btn').className += " blue_btn";
  }
});
```

```css
.blue {
  border: 2px solid blue !important;
}

.blue_btn {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <select class="input_type" id="input_type" name="input_type" style="height:36px" placeholder="Type" required>
  </select>
  <input class="input_activity" type="text" name="activity" placeholder="What do you need to do?" size="60" style="height:32px" required>
  <select class="input_time" name="Time" style="height:36px" required>
    <option value="Start">Start</option>
  </select>
  <select class="input_end" name="end" style="height:36px" required>
    <option value="End">End</option>
  </select>
  <input class="input_btn" type="button" value="Submit!">
</div>
```

Here is where `usersInput` comes from:

```
var usersInput = UICtrl.getInput();
```

Here is where 'getInpu't comes from:

```
return {
    getInput: function() {
        return {
            type: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputType).value,
            activity: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputActivity).value,
            startTime: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputStart).value,
            endTime: document.querySelector(DOMstrings.inputEnd).value
        };
    },
},
```

These are the options to select from the 'type' drop down menu:

```
<select class="input_type" id="input_type" name="input_type" style="height:36px" placeholder="Type" required>
    <option value="">Type</option>
    <option value="health">Health</option>
    <option value="work">Work</option>
    <option value="leisure">Leisure</option>
</select>
```

Please note, I have checked similar questions on the forum but none that I have found have really answered my question. Thanks in advance for your support!

Comment: DOM.inputType does not exist

Comment: Use `.classList.add('blue')` instead of `.className += " blue"` and fix  `document.querySelector(DOM.inputType)` as @Gerard warning.

Comment: DOM.inputType contains the DOM string 'type' which the user inputs. I haven't included all the Javascript code otherwise my post would be very long!

Comment: @BraDev I have implemented the changes you suggested but it still doesn't work? Any other ideas? The DOM.inputType contains the type that the user inputs

Comment: @PaulBailey the dns_nx did a full answer exactly about what I'm saying.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to say exactly what the issue is as I can't see where the different parts of your JS are running... However, my best guess is either:

1. You haven't got your value set correctly on your `select` element (your options are not visible in the HTML provided, I assume they are added via some JS?). Your option needs to have the "Health" value:

```
    <option value="Health">Health<option>
```

2. You are calling this line at the wrong time:

```
   var usersInput = UICtrl.getInput();
```

Try calling this function as the first line inside your event listener, this is because you want to grab the DOM state at that particular moment in time:

```
document.querySelector(DOM.inputType).addEventListener('change', function() {
  var usersInput = UICtrl.getInput();

  if (usersInput.type === "Health") {
    document.querySelector('.input_type').className += " blue";
    document.querySelector('.input_activity').className += " blue";
    document.querySelector('.input_time').className += " blue";
    document.querySelector('.input_end').className += " blue";
    document.querySelector('.input_btn').className += " blue_btn";
  }
});
```

3. There is a spelling error in you `DomStrings` object properties or your `DOM.inputType` property.

Comment: It seems as though putting the var usersInput = UICtrl.getInput(); within the even listener function worked. Does the event listener function not follow the same rules as closures? I thought that this inner function would have access to the outer functions variables?

Comment: it does have access to those variables, however your `usersInput.type` will be stale unless you get the values (which is what you're doing in your `getInput` method) when the value is actually changed, if that makes sense?

Comment: I think I understand....so when the event listener function is invoked (when the user 'changes' the value) the 'getInput' function is invoked and thus, the users input is retrieved. Is that correct?

Comment: yes, exactly :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for your needs, but it depends on how your `<option>`'s look like in the `<select>` element. 
In my example they look like this. But I'm just assuming this, because this information in the original post:

```
<option value="">Please select</option>
<option value="Health">Health</option>
<option value="Soemthing">Soemthing</option>
```

In the code below, I'm checking the value of the `<option>` with

```
...      
if (this.value === "Health") {
...
```

but you can also check the text of the `<option>` value with

```
...
if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].text == "Health") {
...
```

See & check the code

```js
var element = document.getElementById('input_type');
if(element !== null) {
  element.addEventListener('change', function() {
    if (this.value === "Health") {
      document.querySelector('.input_type').classList.add('blue');
      document.querySelector('.input_activity').classList.add('blue');
      document.querySelector('.input_time').classList.add('blue');
      document.querySelector('.input_end').classList.add('blue');
      document.querySelector('.input_btn').classList.add('blue');
    }
    else {
     document.querySelector('.input_type').classList.remove('blue');
      document.querySelector('.input_activity').classList.remove('blue');
      document.querySelector('.input_time').classList.remove('blue');
      document.querySelector('.input_end').classList.remove('blue');
      document.querySelector('.input_btn').classList.remove('blue');
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.blue {
    border: 2px solid blue !important;
}

.blue_btn {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="input">
  <select class="input_type" id="input_type" name="input_type" style="height:36px" placeholder="Type" required>
    <option value="">Please select</option>
    <option value="Health">Health</option>
    <option value="Soemthing">Soemthing</option>
  </select>
  <input class="input_activity" type="text" name="activity" placeholder="What do you need to do?" size="60" style="height:32px" required>
  <select class="input_time" name="Time"  style="height:36px" required>
    <option value="Start">Start</option>
  </select>
  <select class="input_end" name="end" style="height:36px" required>
    <option value="End">End</option>
  </select>
  <input class="input_btn" type="button" value="Submit!">
</div>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately! Still does nothing

Comment: Please see my edits

Comment: If the answer solved your problem, please do not forget to mark it as answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it with the help of all of you! I should have used `usersInput.type` rather than `usersInput.value`. Also the  `var usersInput = UICtrl.getInput();`, needed to be within the event listener function. I always thought that the event listener functions are essentially closures so should therefore have access to the outer functions variables...maybe I am wrong!

here is the new JS code:

```
var element = document.getElementById('input_type');
if (element !== "Type") {
    element.addEventListener('change', function() {
        var usersInput = UICtrl.getInput();
        if (usersInput.type === "health") {
            document.querySelector('.input_type').classList.add('blue');
            document.querySelector('.input_activity').classList.add('blue');
            document.querySelector('.input_time').classList.add('blue');
            document.querySelector('.input_end').classList.add('blue');
            document.querySelector('.input_btn').classList.add('blue');
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

It is because there is nothing like `usersInput`.  `usersInput` is undefined and hence not able to match your if condition which is the reason it is not working. In order to get the value that the user selects you can use `this.value`. Therefore your code needs a little tweak here. Instead of this

```
if (usersInput.type === "Health") {
```

change it to this

```
if (this.value === "Health") {
```

Comment: I will edit my post to explain where 'usersInput' comes from

Comment: Why not just get the arguments from the target attribute of the event?